# Java ASM - Getting LabelNode from AbstractInsnNode

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I have been working with some asm (using Minecraft Forge's Transform class, but it shouldn't be relevant), but I keep crashing with a NoClassDefFoundError and a NullPointerException.  I've already narrowed down what the problem and theoretical solution is.

I'm trying to inject code at operand 23, but the code is to contain a jump to a label that already exists elsewhere (at operand 68) in the code. (m is a methodNode)

```
m.instructions.insert(m.instructions.get(23), ConfigPatch1());
```

Code to inject:

```
InsnList toInject = new InsnList();
toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(ALOAD, 0));
toInject.add(new InsnNode(ICONST_0));
toInject.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/String", "charAt", "(I)C"));
toInject.add(new IntInsnNode(BIPUSH, 33));
toInject.add(new JumpInsnNode(IF_ICMPEQ, 68sLabelNode));
return toInject;
```

The last add should have the label of the LabelNode at operand 68.
I've tried using:

```
(LabelNode) m.instructions.get(68)
```

But then I get a "bad operand on stack" error; seeming to indicate that the cast was bad.  The get returns an AbstractInsnNode.

How can I get the LabelNode from operand 68 so I can use it in my injection?

Thanks you StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you can create a new LabelNode and insert it right before the instruction #68, and then jump to it.

Also, it's more convenient to use [InstructionAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/InstructionAdapter.html) than directly create instructions with `new`.